# git: How to automatically resolve delete/modify conflict?

Tags: git, conflict

I organized my workflow following way:

master branch is for developing, contains source code and some utility scripts.

release branch is distributed and contains executables and some additional files.

When I first created release branch, I removed all source code from it, and added compiled executable. When I want to make next release, I do

`git checkout release`

`git merge --no-ff -Xours master`

And every source file, that changed causes delete/modify conflict even if I use -Xours option. I have to manually delete all conflicted files and then make commit. Is there a way to resolve this conflicts automatically, forcing deleted files to stay deleted?

Comment: You removed the source before, are you going to remove it again?  What is your next 'release' commit going to contain?  Do you want your release commits to keep history, so fetching this release also gets you all previous releases?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Git and for that matter Source Control Management for entirely different way. I am not saying its wrong but you should consider re-thinking on what you want to achieve with git repo.

In general practice, the `release` branch should contain code also. And you always build your production executables from the `release` branch. And then move them to somewhere else.

That said, if you want to keep version of executables too. Create another git repo to keep them there. This way it will easier for you to maintain your executables.

If you are using maven/java then I ll recommend Maven Repo, whose sole purpose is to manage artifacts of the build.

Comment: I use release branch to distribute updates to my clients. I organized repo in this way to have an easy way of patching my releases. May be shell script can do it better, but I hoped, git can deal with it.

Comment: can you use new git repo for executables?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the same repository to store the artefacts generated from your code. You will bloat your history and make pushes and fetches slow for regular development. Eventually you will have to abandon this approach as a new clone will take too long. Standardize on a naming convention for zips of your artefacts and ship them through something else. It could be another git repo, but it can't be the one where you work on your code. You could make a link between the 2 repos via submodules if you like.

Comment: Good answer for the Y problem(release management), but do you know the one for X:) is there a way to auto-resolve a delete/modify conflict (something like "ours")?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete some files from repository and commit some change you need to use -a option. Ad documentation says:

```
-a, --all
   Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been
   modified and deleted, but new files you have not told git about are
   not affected.
```

This clean all my repository from deleted files. And when I merge from others branch I have no conflicts. I am not shure this will help you. I hope yes.